# Reporting Junit xml file

Tags: java, junit

I am a Jenkins user. I want to show JUnit output result in Jenkins. So, I tried to report JUnit xml file with ant and maven. It is so easy and get correct result for me and properly show result in Jenkins. I wrote a project using jsf, seam, spring and iBatis. And I tried to show junit report of that project on jenkins. So, I write an ant script to export JUnit xml file. But it is not working. Ant shown some error related with seam. I can't solve and decide to export junit report file programmatically. So, I search about how to do it. I found no sample code or sample project to do it. I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: No need for ant, use surefire maven plugin.

Comment: Yes. But, I research for all way of exporting junit report. Please help me.